# Android Trying to compare a date with the current date, but does not work

Tags: android, date

I have a simple test program where I create a date object as
Date g=new Date(2011, 4, 2);
now this should be less then today, so
if ( now.getTime()>g.getTime() )
    Toast.makeText(this, "here.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
the if then does not go off?

I checked my android emulater and has a date as
May 2, 2011
do I wrote the following code
       Date g=new Date(2011, 3, 2);
        Date now=new Date();
        long b=g.getTime();
        long a=now.getTime();
and b is bigger then a, how????
Ted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the 3-argument Date constructor (which is deprecated), the year parameter is the number of years since 1900, so when you pass 2011 you're actually getting 3911.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: Hi,I called the getyear on the date being return by current data and got 111 instad of 2011.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Calendar` object:
[Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) cal = new [GregorianCalendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)()

Comment: Hi,I never new about the caalender object, thank you for the info.